# ferret / acts_as_ferret : Specify that a field should be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ferret, acts-as-ferret

This relates to the lucene-based search engine, Ferret.
https://github.com/dbalmain/ferret

Let's say i have a model with two fields, `myfield1` and `myfield2`.  I want to get records that have myfield equal to "foo", or that have `null` (or an empty string) for myfield but have myfield2 set to "foo".

I DON'T want to get records that have, for example, myfield = "bar" and myfield2 = "foo".  So, it's not as simple as just saying "myfield:foo || myfield2: foo" - i only want to look at myfield2 if myfield is empty.

The sql equivalent would be `where (myfield = 'foo') or ((myfield is null or myfield = '') and myfield2 = 'foo')`.  What would the ferret search string equivalent of this be?

The following **doesn't** work, but it's an example of the sort of thing I'm after:

```
"myfield:foo || (myfield:<blank> && myfield2:foo)"
```

thanks, Max

BTW in case it's relevant i'm using acts_as_ferret in ruby on rails, but i think my question really just relates to a ferret search string.  I'm using the ferret gem, v=0.11.6

EDIT: Slightly dirty-feeling solution below, would still like to know if it's possible just with the query string like above.

OK, i got around this by adding a new method, "myfield_blank":

```
def myfield_blank
  myfield_blank?.to_s
end
```

then adding `myfield_blank => {},` to my acts_as_ferret index definition.  So now i can say

```
"myfield:foo || (myfield_blank:true && myfield2:foo)"
```

This works but like I say i'd still like to know if I can just do it in the query, without making new fields:  this approach would be unacceptably hacky if i wanted to do it for lots of different fields.  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [source](https://github.com/dbalmain/ferret/blob/5cb10dd02c467a0fae0329009b263bbcbb8afed0/c/src/q_wildcard.c#L34) `?*` should match any nonempty string, so you can try to do it this way:

```
'myfield:"foo" || (-myfield:"?*" && myfield2:"foo")'
```

And also I don't really see why `'myfield:"foo" || (myfield:"" && myfield2:"foo")'` shouldn't work, but you probably already tried it...

Comment: Ah, "minus" query, of course, should have thought of that!  The minus, and the `?*` (i didn't need the quotes around it) worked.  I'd not encountered `?*` for "a non-empty string" before.  Just to be clear, this worked: `"myfield:foo || (-myfield:?* && myfield2:foo)"`.  many thanks!